# Using TensorFlow in windows

Tags: docker, installation, windows-10, tensorflow

I am trying to configure TensorFlow deep learning library for my windows 10.I used following link for the configuration

[TensorFlow Installation in windows](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-install-and-run-tensorflow-on-a-windows-pc/)

Following are outputs from my docker terminal and windows.

**From docker terminal**

[image]

**From windows commandprompt**
[image]

Now I want to ask how would I use TensorFlow now since it seems to me as everything is working properly?

**Update**

Right Now I am getting following error

[image]

Docker ps command gave following output

[image]

**virtual box status**

[image]

**Python and TensorFlow are running well inside a cmd but I am not being able to fire up Jupyton Notebook**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the second-last line of the log:

```
[... NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/
```

Since you passed the `-p 8888:8888` flag to `docker run`, you can open a web browser in Windows and connect to `http://<ip address>:8888` (where `<ip address>` is the IP of the VirtualBox VM that is listed when you do `docker-machine ls`) to get a Jupyter (IPython) notebook through which you can interact with Python and TensorFlow.

Comment: Please see my update.It did not even work without /tree

Comment: What output do you get if you run `docker ps` in another terminal?

Comment: Please check now I have added new information at bottom of my question.

Comment: when  I used "docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow /bin/bash" in command prompt then from shell it worked ok but I am not getting fired it up in browser on jupyter notebooks

Comment: It looks like the container is no longer running. Is the command prompt in which you ran `docker run` still open, and showing the same message?

Comment: I have seen container in vbox they are running but the command prompt is showing same message.

Comment: The `docker ps` command lists all running containers, so if it gives an empty output, the container does not seem to be running. What output do you see from VirtualBox to make you think it *is* running?

Comment: Can you add the exact message to your question?

Comment: What specific information do you require I would post that?

Comment: You said "I have seen container in vbox they are running" and "it is just showing running"; what screen is giving you that information?

Comment: I have updated that information but I am not sure if running status here would also mean running in true sense?

Comment: Ah, one possibility is that you might need to enter the IP address of the VirtualBox VM instead of `localhost` when you enter the address in your web browser. You can get the IP from the URL column when you run `docker-machine ls`. (It looks like there are two possible VMs, so you might need to try both.) The web address will be `http://...:8888/`, where `...` is the IP of the appropriate VM.

Comment: Same error when I tried VM's IP it came up with "192.168.99.100:8888" cannot be reached and same for 101 IP.I am also sorry as I am bothering you.

Comment: after reinstalling and using ip I figured it out thanks brother.